# Definitions of dielectric constant and relative permittivity? How do they differ?

Tags: electrostatics, definition, dielectric

It's all about the definition, as in how they both are defined.

> My book defines dielectric constant as the proportionality constant
> $$K=\frac{\sigma}{\sigma-\sigma_p}$$
> where $\sigma$ is the surface charge density of the capacitor, and $\sigma_p$ is the surface charge density induced on the dielectric due to polarisation.

> And then it defines permittivity as
> $$\epsilon=\epsilon_0K $$

Many websites on the Internet including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/relative_permittivity) say that they are defined the same.

On the other hand, [this website](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-dielectric-constant-and-relative-permittivity/amp/) says that they are distinguished for their scope - the dielectric constant is only defined for dielectrics, but the relative permittivity is defined for all materials.

My question is, how do we define them into the convention used today? And how do you then *define* permittivity or is it the other way round?

Comment: Usually it's a dielectric tensor and the permittivity depends upon this tensor and an additional constant (i.e., permittivity of free space).  The dielectric tensor is usually defined from the electric susceptibility tensor.

Comment: @honeste_vivere: May you please clarify that mathematically? And, if possible, in elementary terms, I am not used to tensors much. (I know very less but will try to understand)

Comment: The necessity of tensors is for anisotropic media – fields behave differently in different directions and for different polarizations.  When everything is isotropic and spatial attenuation/amplification is ignored, then the tensor can be reduced to a constant.  For most purposes, the tensor form is just a 3x3 matrix (i.e., rank-2 tensor).

Comment: @honeste_vivere: So, that means "dielectric constant" and "relative permittivity" are defined differently, and "permittivity" is defined in terms of relative permittivity?